How do i install HAXM?
I am setting up my development environment in visual studio code and want to create a virtual device as my android emulator but i need to download and install HAXM. I have downloaded it but the installation always fails. What do i do?
I tried to download and install in vs code but it failed. I also downloaded and installed it manually but the vs code does not recognize it.
